# Facing issue with Calendar object

Tags: java, android, date, time, calendar

I have a task in which i need to set hour, minute, meridian programmatically to Calendar object and need to display time in a format hh:mm a. Here below is my code so far.

```
Calendar calendar = (Calendar)dateNtime.clone();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 12);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, 1);

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
    String str = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

Where dateNTime is an existing calendar object which i have to use in constructing new one.

All is going fine except only a case while i set 12PM. it always format hh:mm a and results 12:00AM while it should be 12:00PM.

please help if anybody have a good experience with Calendar object and it's known issue or provide me if there is a good tutorial link.

Comment: Please provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. Personally I think I'd just set the HOUR to your target hour, adding 12 if you're trying to set it to PM...

Comment: Note that if you set the hour to *0* and then set AM_PM to 1, you get your desired result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `HOUR` field is [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR) as:

> Field number for get and set indicating the hour of the morning or afternoon. HOUR is used for the 12-hour clock (0 - 11).

So instead of setting it to 12, you should set it to 0.

Personally I'd just set the `HOUR_OF_DAY` field, adding 12 hours if you want to make it PM - and don't set the `AM_PM` field at all.

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern API:**

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Replace JVM's default timezone, ZoneId.systemDefault() with the applicable
        // timezone e.g. ZoneId.of("America/New_York")
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                            .withHour(12)
                            .withMinute(0);
        System.out.println(zdt);

        // Get and display just time in default format
        LocalTime time = zdt.toLocalTime();
        System.out.println(time);

        // Display just time in a custom format
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
        // Alternatively, dtf.format(time);
        String formatted = dtf.format(zdt);
        System.out.println(formatted);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-06-06T12:00:15.855986+01:00[Europe/London]
12:00:15.855986
12:00 PM
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/qiV5tE)

### How to convert `Calendar` to `java.time` type?

```
Instant instant = calendar.toInstant();
// Replace JVM's default timezone, ZoneId.systemDefault() with the applicable
// timezone e.g. ZoneId.of("America/New_York")
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

### What if I need `Calendar` object from `java.time` type?

For any reason, if you need to convert this object of `ZonedDateTime` to an object of `java.util.Calendar`, you can do so as follows:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(Date.from(zdt.toInstant()));
```

Learn more about `java.time`, the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Sometimes, comments get deleted and therefore quoting below a valuable comment from Ole V.V.:

> For a more accurate conversion to `Calendar` you may use
> `GregorianCalendar.from(zdt)`

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>